# How to display the item to be deleted in the dialog using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the delete dialog using Jquery. The problem is I cannot display the item in the prompt or dialog box. For example the dialog box will prompt like this: "Are you sure you want to delete this Product item?". The word "Product" must be diplayed in the dialog box so that the user will be informed on what to be deleted.

JQuery code:

```
 var del = function($element) {
              $('#remove').dialog({
                title: 'Delete',
                dialogClass: "clickoncloseoutside",
                open: function () {

                var prompt = 'Are you sure want to this'.$(this.href).' item?'; //it doesn't work
                $('.delete_link').data(this.href); //it doesn't work

                //It should display like this: Are you sure you want to delete this Product item?

                $(this).html(prompt);
                },
                buttons: {
                  "Delete item": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $element.data('allow', true); // Allow the next click to proceed
                    $element[0].click(); // Hit the DOM native click event
                  },
                  Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
                }
              });
            }

            $('.delete_link').click(function(e) {
              if (!$(this).data('allow')) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                del($(this));
              }
            });
```

Html code:

```
<td><a class="delete_link" href='del.php?&opr=delMedicine&id=<?php echo $test['id'];?>' title="Delete">

<div id="remove" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you need to refer to the link using the variable `$element` that you are taking in as a parameter in the function `del()`.

For example, using the href attribute like your example:

```
//$element is the clicked link
var prompt = 'Are you sure want to this' + $element.attr('href') + ' item?'; 
$('.delete_link').data($element.attr('href'));
```

Comment: Note that this will show the `href` attribute of the link, and not the link text because I was playing off of the example that you posted. To get the link text you can use `$element.html()`.